# Не выдается роль с помощью сообщения Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, role

Помогите разобраться. Бот должен выдавать роль, когда получит сообщение с необходимым текстом, к примеру, "Группа С118". В итоге не выдает никаких ошибок синтаксиса и тп, просто молчит.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get
@Bot.event 
async def on_message(msg):         
    member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
    if "text in message" in msg.content:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = "")
        await Bot.add_roles(member, role) 
Bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не правильное построение кода.

Метод [on_member_join()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) - событие и используется так:

```
@Bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await bot.process_commands(message)#также надо добавить это, подробнее смотрите ниже. 
    print(f'На сервере новый пользователь {member.mention}')
```

[process_commands()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) - это надо что бы бот выдел команди(пример /help, если этого не будет он не ответит на команду)

Метод [on_message()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) - тоже событие и используется так:

```
@Bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'Hello':
        await message.channel.send(f'Hello {message.member.mention}')
```

И так, если вы хотите что бы выдавалась роль когда пользователь заходит на сервер то надо так:

```
@Bot.event 
async def on_member_join(member):         
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = "")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

А если по определенному слове:

```
@Bot.event 
async def on_message(message):  
    await bot.process_commands(message)       
    if message.content == 'Роль':
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = "")
        await message.member.add_roles(role)
```